# What's the theoretical loophole that allows F# (or any functional language) to apply a function mulitple times on the same input

Tags: functional-programming, f#

In F# if I write

```
let p = printfn "something"
```

it will evaluate the expression once. Any subsequent references to `p` will evaluate to unit.
From a theoretical perspective, the definition of a function, this makes sense. A function should only return the same result for the same input.

However if I want the side-effect to occur (i.e. the output to the screen), then I need the pass an argument to p. Typically this argument is the `unit` value.

```
let p () = printfn "something"
```

But why will F# evaluate the function each time, when the argument is the same each time the function is applied? Surely the same reasoning should apply as in the first case? The input to the function `p` doesn't change therefore there is no need to evaluate it more than once.

Comment: I don't know f#, but the first looks like you're letting p be the value that `printfn "something"` immediately returns, and the second looks like you're defining `p` to be a function that can be called.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah that's right. maybe that's all it is and i'm overthinking it.

Comment: It works this way specifically for the purpose of allowing effects. Not every functional language works this way though. For example, Haskell and PureScript are what is called "purely functional", which in this context means that effects are reified as actual values, rather than happening as a consequence of calling a function.

Comment: @sashang if that's the case, then that *is* all. Then it's just how this language is designed, as Fyodor says.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The action `printfn` is, strictly speaking, not a function. It is, particularly, not a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), because it's not [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). This is possible because F# isn't a strictly functional language (it's a 'functional first' language). It makes no explicit distinction between pure functions and impure actions.

The return value of `printfn "something"` is `()` (`unit`), which means that `p` is bound to the unit value `()`. The fact that `something` is printed on the screen is a side effect of evaluating the expression.

F# is an eagerly evaluated language. That's why you see `something` printed on the screen as a side effect of binding `printfn "something"` to `p`. Once the expression is evaluated, `p` is only bound to `()` - the value.

F# doesn't memoize function calls, so when you change `p` to a function, it'll evaluate the function every time you call it with `()`. Since all functions *can* be impure, the compiler can't tell whether or not memoization would be appropriate, so it doesn't do that.

Other languages do this in different ways. Haskell, for example, is lazily evaluated, and also explicitly distinguishes between pure functions and impure actions, so it can apply different optimization in cases like these.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer given in the comments, the first `p` is an immutable value, while the second `p` is a function. If you refer to an immutable value multiple times, then (obviously) its value doesn't change over time. But if you invoke a function multiple times, it executes each time, *even if the arguments are the same each time*.

Note that this is true even for pure functional languages, such as Haskell. If you want to avoid this execution cost, there's a specific technique called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) that can be used to return cached results when the same inputs occur again. However, memoization has its own costs, and I'm not aware of any mainstream functional language that automatically memoizes all function calls.

Comment: For Haskell, it's not strictly speaking true. Because Haskell is pure, the compiler is free to reuse subexpression values in multiple places, and it does so under certain circumstances (when it can be sure that it would lead to better performance). So in Haskell the function may or may not be executed on every call. In F#, however, the compiler cannot reasonably do this, because every function could perform effects, so it has to honestly execute every function on every call.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin so in Haskell would it be correct to say that a function is not always evaluated/executed, and whether it is, depends on the nature of the arguments given to the function?

Comment: More of less, yes. But if you put it that way, it would be true for another reason as well: Haskell uses normal evaluation order, so a function might be never evaluated even if it's only referenced once.